# Why is JSON type-safe?

Tags: javascript, json, type-safety

I read that someone claims JSON is **type-safe**. 
I know that plain Javascript is not. But how could a representation format like JSON can be type-safe ?

Answer (score 4):

I think it depends on what you mean. In most ways of looking at json it isn't. However you can't send more than the default types, so no executable code etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you are looking for is this: JSON data will never do anything on its own; it is not active.  Only when you unpack it, the items might be dangerous.

Example: data is harmless, but $('#data').html(data.my_script); there data.my_script could contain harmful content.

While, if you directly inject javascript into your webpage (call it my_script), that script might do anything.

---

Anything more specific you think could go wrong?  We can see if JSON helps